# div with position fixed inside the scrollable div, overlapping the scrollbar

Tags: html, position, scrollbar, fixed

I'd like to fixed position right of the div inside the scrollable div.
But the fixed div just overlaps the parent div's scrollbar!
How to fix it?
Your response would be appreciated
PS: I must use position: fixed to implement this.

```
.content{
    background:#ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin:50px auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow-Y:auto;
}
.fixedmarker{
    background:#f00;
    color:#fff;
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    right: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p40p15j0/

Comment: what you need exactly

Comment: I need the .fixedmarker div not overlap on the .content div's scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want there is a fixed div in your div with a scroll bar?
If that's it, here's the CSS code:

```css
.happy{
     background: #ccc;
     width: 100%;
     height: 200px;
     margin: 50px auto;
     position: relative;
     overflow-Y: auto;
    
}

.fixedmarker {
     background: # f00;
     color: #fff;
     position: fixed;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     right: 25px;
}
```

To see my version of the project:
https://jsfiddle.net/Warthele/kqbyscpm/4/